# Add,Edit and Delete XML multi level node using c#

Tags: c#, xml, menu, element

This is my XML structure, I need a C# program to add, edit and delete the element with N level.

```
<root>
  <TopLevelMenu ID="&amp;File">
    <MenuItem ID="New" OnClick="_New" />
    <MenuItem ID="Open" OnClick="_Open" />
    <MenuItem ID="-" />
    <MenuItem ID="Close" OnClick="_Close" />
    <MenuItem ID="-" />
    <MenuItem ID="E&amp;xit" OnClick="_Exit" />
  </TopLevelMenu>
  <TopLevelMenu ID="&amp;Edit">
    <MenuItem ID="Undo" OnClick="_Undo" />
    <MenuItem ID="-" />
    <MenuItem ID="Cut" OnClick="_Cut" />
    <MenuItem ID="Copy" OnClick="_Copy" />
    <MenuItem ID="Paste" OnClick="_Paste" />
    <MenuItem ID="-" />
    <MenuItem ID="Options">
      <MenuItem ID="Sub Menu Item">
        <MenuItem ID="Sub Sub Menu Item" />
      </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
  </TopLevelMenu>
</root>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service, nor is it somewhere to hire a freelancer. You need to research this and attempt a solution yourself. Post additional questions if you run into issues *whilst coding your solution*.

Comment: yes, Just I tried to load this xml to dataset. it was loading as two tables.  table[0] - ToLevelMenu, table[1]- next level menu item.  muti level node was not loaded. that is the problem to me.

Comment: Several approaches possible, to me [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115(v=vs.110).aspx) and [LinqToXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb387098.aspx) being the most useful to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this recursive code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication34
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
            "<root>\n" +
              "<TopLevelMenu ID=\"Imports&amp;FileImports\">\n" +
                "<MenuItem ID=\"ImportsNewImports\" OnClick=\"Imports_NewImports\"/>\n" +
                "<MenuItem ID=\"ImportsOpenImports\" OnClick=\"Imports_OpenImports\"/>\n" +
                "<MenuItem ID=\"Imports-Imports\" />\n" +
                "<MenuItem ID=\"ImportsCloseImports\" OnClick=\"Imports_CloseImports\"/>\n" +
                "<MenuItem ID=\"Imports-Imports\"/>\n" +
                "<MenuItem ID=\"ImportsE&amp;xitImports\" OnClick=\"Imports_ExitImports\"/>\n" +
              "</TopLevelMenu\n>" +
              "<TopLevelMenu ID=\"Imports&amp;EditImports\">\n" +
                "<MenuItem ID=\"ImportsUndoImports\" OnClick=\"Imports_UndoImports\"/>\n" +
                "<MenuItem ID=\"Imports-Imports\"/>\n" +
                "<MenuItem ID=\"ImportsCutImports\" OnClick=\"Imports_CutImports\"/>\n" +
                "<MenuItem ID=\"ImportsCopyImports\" OnClick=\"Imports_CopyImports\"/>\n" +
                "<MenuItem ID=\"ImportsPasteImports\" OnClick=\"Imports_PasteImports\"/>\n" +
                "<MenuItem ID=\"Imports-Imports\"/>\n" +
                "<MenuItem ID=\"ImportsOptionsImports\">\n" +
                  "<MenuItem ID=\"ImportsSub Menu ItemImports\">\n" +
                    "<MenuItem ID=\"ImportsSub Sub Menu ItemImports\"/>\n" +
                  "</MenuItem>\n" +
                "</MenuItem>\n" +
              "</TopLevelMenu>\n" +
            "</root>\n";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
            var results = doc.Descendants("TopLevelMenu").Elements("MenuItem").Select(y => GetMenu(y)).ToList();

        }
        static object GetMenu(XElement element)
        {
            if (!element.HasElements)
            {
                return element.Attribute("ID").Value;
            }
            else
            {
                return (new { id = element.Attribute("ID").Value, child = GetMenu(element.Element("MenuItem"))});
            }
        }

    }
}
```